# How to reload Kafka Connect source/sink .jar without stopping and starting Confluent?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am building my Kafka Connect source/sink connectors with the process of:

1. edit code and export .jar
2. confluent start
3. confluent load
4. confluent status
5. confluent log connect
6. confluent unload
7. confluent stop
8. repeat

So I am starting and stopping all of Confluent every time I change the code, which takes a while. Is there a way I can speed up the process to have it use the new .jar or something without restarting the whole thing to make the debugging process go more smoothly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to stop and start `connect` process, not the entire Confluent Platform

In any case, a JVM restart is required for Kafka Connect to load new code

In a production environment, you'd likely be using systemctl to restart the Connect process

Comment: Thanks! `./bin/confluent connect stop` `./bin/confluent connect start` gets the updated .jar.